# Why Vasicek model on a tree is a bad choice for pricing American option on credit prepayment?

Tags: option-pricing, american-options, binomial-tree, vasicek, lattice

I have an American option on a credit prepayment, i.e. the holder of the option can prepay the remaining credit if the interest rate falls below the initial strike. The pricing of this option was done on a discrete lattice (binomial tree) assuming that a risk-free part of the interest rate follows the one-factor Vasicek short rate model.

I was told that Vasicek on a tree is a terrible choice of model implementation and that one should either use Monte Carlo simulation with the Vasicek model or use the Hull-White model on a tree. I was also told that this is a bad practice in general to use one-factor models on trees. Can anyone elaborate on it?

Comment: Both models are mean reverting, so the direction and intensity of their movements depend on the long term mean of the value. As a result, you can get negative values when the value is higher than the long term mean. If you want to use a tree with these models, then it will need to be modified to account for this. This either adds another layer of complexity and/or lowers accuracy. Today, people generally use Monte Carlo simulations instead of trees because they are more efficient.

Comment: @KevinK., can you give a link to any source with discussion of the tree modifications needed?